# Redactor-js and blurCallback

Tags: javascript, jquery, redactor

I have radactor v9.0.4 ( http://imperavi.com/redactor/ ) and I have a problem with blurCallback event, because editor trigger this event when I click on his own toolbar.

I want to use blur event beacuse when user click somewhere outside editor I want to turn it off. But click on, for example, bold text blurCallback calls. Sample code with my workaround

```
$that.redactor({
    blurCallback: function(e)
    {
        if(e.relatedTarget !== null)return;

        // turn off editor
    }
});
```

As you can see I've tried to do this with relatedTarget but this won't work on firefox. Do you have any ideas how I can fix that?

Comment: The issue still persists for air toolbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be fixed in Redactor version 9.1.6. See [changelog](http://imperavi.com/redactor/log) for more details.